# separator lines + vertical alignment problem

Tags: tables

I'm using Excel2Latex macro and I've got the result like this:

% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Table 3'

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow,color}
\usepackage[Table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
\onecolumn
% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Table 3'
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
\begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth}
    \begin{tabular}{lcccccccccccccccc}
\cmidrule{2-16}    \multicolumn{1}{r|}{} &
  \multicolumn{5}{c|}{\textbf{20s}} &
  \multicolumn{5}{c|}{\textbf{50s}} &
  \multicolumn{5}{c|}{\textbf{80s}} &

  \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Parameter}} &
  \begin{sideways}RCP2.6\end{sideways} &
  \begin{sideways}RCP4.5\end{sideways} &
  \begin{sideways}RCP6\end{sideways} &
  \begin{sideways}RCP8.5\end{sideways} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\begin{sideways}Average\end{sideways}} &
  \begin{sideways}RCP2.6\end{sideways} &
  \begin{sideways}RCP4.5\end{sideways} &
  \begin{sideways}RCP6\end{sideways} &
  \begin{sideways}RCP8.5\end{sideways} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\begin{sideways}Average\end{sideways}} &
  \begin{sideways}RCP2.6\end{sideways} &
  \begin{sideways}RCP4.5\end{sideways} &
  \begin{sideways}RCP6\end{sideways} &
  \begin{sideways}RCP8.5\end{sideways} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\begin{sideways}Average\end{sideways}} &
  \textbf{Average change from 20s to 80s}
  \\
\cmidrule{1-17}    \rowcolor[rgb]{ 1,1,1} \textbf{ALPHA\_BF} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .149,  .149,  .149}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{1.0} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .149,  .149,  .149}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{1.0} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .149,  .149,  .149}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{1.0} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .149,  .149,  .149}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{1.0} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .149,  .149,  .149}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{1.0} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .149,  .149,  .149}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{1.0} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .149,  .149,  .149}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{1.0} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .149,  .149,  .149}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{1.0} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .149,  .149,  .149}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{1.0} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .149,  .149,  .149}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{1.0} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .149,  .149,  .149}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{1.0} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .149,  .149,  .149}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{1.0} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .149,  .149,  .149}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{1.0} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .149,  .149,  .149}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{1.0} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .149,  .149,  .149}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{1.0} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{0.0}
  \\
\rowcolor[rgb]{ 1,1,1} \textbf{ESCO} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .196,  .192,  .192}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{2.8} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .188,  .188,  .188}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{2.5} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .2,  .196,  .196}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{2.9} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .192,  .192,  .192}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{2.7} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .192,  .192,  .192}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{2.7} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .184,  .184,  .184}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{2.4} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .184,  .18,  .18}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{2.3} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .188,  .188,  .188}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{2.6} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .18,  .18,  .18}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{2.2} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .184,  .184,  .184}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{2.4} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .192,  .188,  .188}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{2.7} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .18,  .18,  .18}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{2.3} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .184,  .184,  .184}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{2.4} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .176,  .176,  .176}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{2.1} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .18,  .18,  .18}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{2.3} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{17.8}
  \\
\rowcolor[rgb]{ 1,1,1} \textbf{CH\_K(II)} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .192,  .192,  .192}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{2.8} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .192,  .192,  .192}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{2.8} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .188,  .184,  .184}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{2.5} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .188,  .188,  .188}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{2.6} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .192,  .188,  .188}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{2.7} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .2,  .196,  .196}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{3.0} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .196,  .192,  .192}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{2.8} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .192,  .188,  .188}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{2.6} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .196,  .192,  .192}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{2.8} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .196,  .192,  .192}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{2.8} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .192,  .188,  .188}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{2.7} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .2,  .196,  .196}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{2.9} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .192,  .188,  .188}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{2.6} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .2,  .196,  .196}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{2.9} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .196,  .192,  .192}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{2.8} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .404,  .396,  .396}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{-5.0}
  \\
\rowcolor[rgb]{ 1,1,1} \textbf{SNO50COV} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .22,  .216,  .216}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{3.7} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .224,  .224,  .224}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{3.9} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .224,  .22,  .22}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{3.9} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .227,  .224,  .224}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{4.0} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .224,  .224,  .224}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{3.9} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .224,  .22,  .22}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{3.9} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .231,  .231,  .231}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{4.2} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .227,  .224,  .224}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{4.0} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .239,  .235,  .235}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{4.4} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .231,  .227,  .227}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{4.2} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .224,  .224,  .224}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{3.9} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .235,  .231,  .231}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{4.3} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .239,  .239,  .239}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{4.5} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .259,  .255,  .255}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{5.2} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .239,  .235,  .235}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{4.5} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .302,  .298,  .298}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{-13.4}
  \\
\rowcolor[rgb]{ 1,1,1} \textbf{SFTMP} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .259,  .255,  .255}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{5.2} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .263,  .259,  .259}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{5.3} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .259,  .255,  .255}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{5.2} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .267,  .263,  .263}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{5.5} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .263,  .259,  .259}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{5.3} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .263,  .259,  .259}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{5.3} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .255,  .251,  .251}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{5.0} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .259,  .255,  .255}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{5.2} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .251,  .247,  .247}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{4.9} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .255,  .255,  .255}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{5.1} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .263,  .259,  .259}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{5.4} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .255,  .251,  .251}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{5.1} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .247,  .247,  .247}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{4.8} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .243,  .243,  .243}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{4.6} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .251,  .251,  .251}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{5.0} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .549,  .537,  .537}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{7.1}
  \\
\rowcolor[rgb]{ 1,1,1} \textbf{CH\_K(I)} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .271,  .267,  .267}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{5.6} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .271,  .267,  .267}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{5.6} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .271,  .267,  .267}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{5.6} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .263,  .259,  .259}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{5.3} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .267,  .263,  .263}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{5.5} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .271,  .267,  .267}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{5.6} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .275,  .271,  .271}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{5.7} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .271,  .267,  .267}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{5.7} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .271,  .267,  .267}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{5.6} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .271,  .267,  .267}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{5.6} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .267,  .263,  .263}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{5.5} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .271,  .267,  .267}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{5.6} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .271,  .267,  .267}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{5.7} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .259,  .255,  .255}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{5.2} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .267,  .263,  .263}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{5.5} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .471,  .459,  .459}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{0.4}
  \\
\rowcolor[rgb]{ 1,1,1} \textbf{SNOCOVMX} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .31,  .306,  .306}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{7.1} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .306,  .302,  .302}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{7.0} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .306,  .302,  .302}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{7.0} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .306,  .302,  .302}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{7.0} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .306,  .302,  .302}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{7.0} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .31,  .306,  .306}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{7.2} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .31,  .306,  .306}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{7.1} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .306,  .302,  .302}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{7.0} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .322,  .318,  .318}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{7.6} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .314,  .31,  .31}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{7.2} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .318,  .31,  .31}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{7.4} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .314,  .306,  .306}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{7.2} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .325,  .318,  .318}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{7.6} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .369,  .361,  .361}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{9.2} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .333,  .325,  .325}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{7.9} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .325,  .318,  .318}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{-11.6}
  \\
\rowcolor[rgb]{ 1,1,1} \textbf{GWQMN} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .349,  .345,  .345}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{8.6} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .353,  .345,  .345}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{8.7} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .349,  .345,  .345}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{8.6} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .349,  .341,  .341}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{8.6} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .349,  .345,  .345}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{8.6} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .349,  .341,  .341}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{8.5} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .345,  .341,  .341}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{8.5} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .341,  .333,  .333}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{8.3} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .333,  .325,  .325}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{8.0} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .341,  .337,  .337}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{8.3} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .349,  .341,  .341}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{8.5} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .341,  .337,  .337}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{8.3} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .329,  .322,  .322}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{7.8} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .318,  .314,  .314}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{7.4} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .333,  .329,  .329}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{8.0} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .553,  .541,  .541}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{7.3}
  \\
\rowcolor[rgb]{ 1,1,1} \textbf{SMTMP} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .361,  .353,  .353}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{9.0} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .361,  .353,  .353}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{9.0} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .349,  .345,  .345}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{8.6} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .361,  .353,  .353}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{9.0} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .357,  .353,  .353}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{8.9} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .353,  .349,  .349}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{8.8} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .353,  .349,  .349}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{8.8} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .365,  .357,  .357}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{9.1} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .361,  .353,  .353}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{9.0} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .357,  .353,  .353}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{8.9} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .357,  .349,  .349}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{8.9} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .353,  .349,  .349}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{8.8} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .361,  .353,  .353}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{9.0} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .384,  .376,  .376}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{9.9} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .365,  .357,  .357}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{9.2} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .431,  .424,  .424}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{-2.8}
  \\
\rowcolor[rgb]{ 1,1,1} \textbf{SOL\_AWC} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .416,  .408,  .408}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{11.1} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .42,  .412,  .412}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{11.3} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .424,  .416,  .416}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{11.4} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .416,  .408,  .408}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{11.0} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .42,  .412,  .412}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{11.2} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .4,  .396,  .396}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{10.6} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .396,  .388,  .388}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{10.3} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .412,  .404,  .404}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{10.9} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .384,  .38,  .38}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{10.0} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .396,  .388,  .388}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{10.4} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .404,  .4,  .4}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{10.7} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .392,  .384,  .384}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{10.2} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .38,  .376,  .376}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{9.8} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .357,  .353,  .353}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{8.9} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .384,  .376,  .376}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{9.9} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .627,  .612,  .612}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{13.4}
  \\
\rowcolor[rgb]{ 1,1,1} \textbf{CN2} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .384,  .376,  .376}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{9.8} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .369,  .365,  .365}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{9.4} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .38,  .373,  .373}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{9.8} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .384,  .376,  .376}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{9.9} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .38,  .373,  .373}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{9.7} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .416,  .408,  .408}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{11.1} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .431,  .424,  .424}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{11.7} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .404,  .396,  .396}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{10.6} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .435,  .427,  .427}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{11.8} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .424,  .416,  .416}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{11.4} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .42,  .412,  .412}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{11.2} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .498,  .49,  .49}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{14.2} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .451,  .443,  .443}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{12.4} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .498,  .486,  .486}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{14.1} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .471,  .463,  .463}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{13.1} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .149,  .149,  .149}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{-26.1}
  \\
\rowcolor[rgb]{ 1,1,1} \textbf{CANMX} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .475,  .467,  .467}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{13.3} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .471,  .463,  .463}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{13.1} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .467,  .459,  .459}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{13.0} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .494,  .482,  .482}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{14.0} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .478,  .467,  .467}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{13.4} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .471,  .463,  .463}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{13.2} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .471,  .463,  .463}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{13.2} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .471,  .463,  .463}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{13.2} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .471,  .463,  .463}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{13.2} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .471,  .463,  .463}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{13.2} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .467,  .455,  .455}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{13.0} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .459,  .447,  .447}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{12.6} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .471,  .459,  .459}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{13.1} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .439,  .431,  .431}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{12.0} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .455,  .447,  .447}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{12.6} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .541,  .529,  .529}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{6.3}
  \\
\rowcolor[rgb]{ 1,1,1} \textbf{DDRAIN} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .502,  .494,  .494}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{14.3} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .51,  .498,  .498}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{14.6} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .525,  .514,  .514}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{15.2} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .486,  .475,  .475}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{13.7} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .502,  .494,  .494}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{14.4} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .486,  .475,  .475}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{13.7} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .471,  .459,  .459}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{13.1} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .478,  .467,  .467}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{13.4} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .467,  .459,  .459}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{13.0} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .475,  .463,  .463}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{13.3} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .475,  .463,  .463}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{13.3} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .463,  .451,  .451}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{12.8} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .451,  .443,  .443}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{12.4} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .427,  .42,  .42}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{11.6} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .455,  .443,  .443}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{12.5} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .651,  .635,  .635}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{15.3}
  \\
\rowcolor[rgb]{ 1,1,1} \textbf{SURLAG} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .478,  .467,  .467}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{13.3} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .463,  .451,  .451}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{12.8} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .471,  .463,  .463}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{13.2} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .475,  .463,  .463}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{13.2} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .471,  .459,  .459}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{13.1} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .494,  .482,  .482}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{14.0} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .486,  .475,  .475}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{13.7} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .502,  .49,  .49}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{14.3} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .478,  .467,  .467}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{13.4} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .486,  .478,  .478}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{13.8} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .482,  .475,  .475}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{13.6} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .463,  .455,  .455}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{12.9} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .482,  .471,  .471}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{13.6} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .482,  .471,  .471}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{13.5} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .478,  .467,  .467}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{13.4} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .443,  .435,  .435}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{-1.8}
  \\
\rowcolor[rgb]{ 1,1,1} \textbf{CH\_N(I)} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .518,  .51,  .51}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{14.9} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .51,  .498,  .498}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{14.6} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .522,  .51,  .51}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{15.1} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .51,  .498,  .498}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{14.6} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .514,  .502,  .502}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{14.8} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .522,  .51,  .51}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{15.1} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .506,  .494,  .494}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{14.5} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .502,  .49,  .49}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{14.3} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .506,  .494,  .494}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{14.4} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .51,  .498,  .498}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{14.6} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .51,  .502,  .502}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{14.7} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .51,  .498,  .498}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{14.5} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .506,  .498,  .498}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{14.5} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .482,  .471,  .471}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{13.5} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .502,  .49,  .49}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{14.3} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .506,  .498,  .498}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{3.5}
  \\
\rowcolor[rgb]{ 1,1,1} \textbf{TIMP} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .518,  .51,  .51}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{14.9} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .525,  .514,  .514}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{15.2} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .525,  .514,  .514}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{15.1} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .522,  .51,  .51}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{15.0} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .522,  .51,  .51}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{15.0} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .514,  .502,  .502}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{14.7} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .525,  .514,  .514}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{15.2} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .518,  .506,  .506}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{14.9} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .525,  .514,  .514}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{15.2} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .522,  .51,  .51}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{15.0} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .537,  .525,  .525}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{15.6} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .522,  .51,  .51}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{15.1} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .529,  .518,  .518}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{15.3} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .533,  .522,  .522}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{15.4} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .529,  .518,  .518}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{15.4} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .439,  .431,  .431}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{-2.0}
  \\
\rowcolor[rgb]{ 1,1,1} \textbf{SMFMX} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .557,  .545,  .545}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{16.3} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .573,  .561,  .561}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{16.9} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .549,  .537,  .537}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{16.0} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .565,  .553,  .553}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{16.6} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .561,  .549,  .549}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{16.5} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .565,  .553,  .553}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{16.7} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .576,  .565,  .565}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{17.1} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .561,  .549,  .549}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{16.6} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .584,  .573,  .573}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{17.4} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .573,  .561,  .561}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{17.0} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .553,  .541,  .541}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{16.2} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .573,  .561,  .561}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{17.0} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .588,  .573,  .573}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{17.5} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .604,  .588,  .588}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{18.1} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .58,  .565,  .565}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{17.2} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .416,  .408,  .408}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{-4.1}
  \\
\rowcolor[rgb]{ 1,1,1} \textbf{SMFMN} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .592,  .58,  .58}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{17.7} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .588,  .573,  .573}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{17.5} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .573,  .561,  .561}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{17.0} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .58,  .569,  .569}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{17.2} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .584,  .573,  .573}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{17.4} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .565,  .553,  .553}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{16.7} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .576,  .565,  .565}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{17.1} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .584,  .573,  .573}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{17.4} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .569,  .557,  .557}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{16.9} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .573,  .561,  .561}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{17.0} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .576,  .565,  .565}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{17.1} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .561,  .549,  .549}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{16.5} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .573,  .561,  .561}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{16.9} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .565,  .553,  .553}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{16.6} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .569,  .557,  .557}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{16.8} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .51,  .498,  .498}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{3.6}
  \\
\rowcolor[rgb]{ 1,1,1} \textbf{CH\_N(II)} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .631,  .616,  .616}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{19.0} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .627,  .612,  .612}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{19.0} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .627,  .612,  .612}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{19.0} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .627,  .612,  .612}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{19.0} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .627,  .612,  .612}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{19.0} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .627,  .612,  .612}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{19.0} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .62,  .608,  .608}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{18.8} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .627,  .612,  .612}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{19.0} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .627,  .612,  .612}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{19.0} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .627,  .612,  .612}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{18.9} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .627,  .612,  .612}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{19.0} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .624,  .608,  .608}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{18.8} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .627,  .612,  .612}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{19.0} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .62,  .604,  .604}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{18.7} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .624,  .608,  .608}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{18.9} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .475,  .463,  .463}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{0.7}
  \\
\rowcolor[rgb]{ 1,1,1} \textbf{GDRAIN} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .671,  .655,  .655}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{20.5} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .667,  .651,  .651}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{20.5} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .671,  .655,  .655}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{20.6} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .647,  .647}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{20.3} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .667,  .651,  .651}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{20.5} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .671,  .655,  .655}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{20.6} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .647,  .647}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{20.4} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .667,  .651,  .651}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{20.5} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .647,  .647}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{20.3} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .667,  .651,  .651}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{20.4} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .659,  .647,  .647}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{20.3} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .667,  .651,  .651}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{20.5} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .667,  .651,  .651}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{20.4} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .647,  .647}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{20.3} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .647,  .647}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{20.4} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .471,  .463,  .463}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{0.6}
  \\
\rowcolor[rgb]{ 1,1,1} \textbf{GW\_DELAY} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{20.9} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .678,  .663,  .663}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{21.0} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .678,  .663,  .663}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{20.9} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{21.0} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .678,  .663,  .663}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{21.0} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .678,  .663,  .663}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{21.0} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{21.0} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .678,  .663,  .663}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{20.9} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .678,  .663,  .663}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{21.0} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .678,  .663,  .663}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{21.0} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{21.0} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{21.0} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{21.0} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .678,  .663,  .663}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{20.9} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .678,  .663,  .663}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{21.0} &
  \cellcolor[rgb]{ .463,  .455,  .455}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{-0.1}
  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
\label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

The results look fine. But there are two problems:
1- I need to vertically align the "Parameter" cell at top left and "Average change from 20s to 80s" at top right. 
2- As you can see, the vertical and horizontal lines at the top of table do not cross each other and it has made the table grotesque. Isn't there a way to make it look like a normal table (the lines cover each other?)

I appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: A nice looking table does *not* use vertical lines, except in some very special cases, so I suggest to remove them altogether. The lines are broken because of the vertical padding that  `booktabs` adds around horizontal rules

Comment: @Bernard Thank you so much for your helpful comments.

Answer (score 1):

I propose this, with slightly shorter code and no vertical rules. I didn't use `adjustbox`, which often makes font size inconsistent, and let the table go into both margins, so as to have a font size equal to `footnotesize`, using the `adjustwidth` environment and playing with the value of `\tabcolsep`. Note you don't have to load `colortbl`, since the `[table]` option of `xcolor` does it for you. Also to obtain the alignment the decimal dot, all `\cellcolor` commands have to be  between braces.

```
    \documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{multirow, array}
    \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{siunitx}
    \usepackage{rotating, makecell, changepage}
    \renewcommand\theadfont{\scriptsize\bfseries\color{black}}
    \usepackage{adjustbox}

    \begin{document}
    \onecolumn
    % Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Table 3'
    \begin{table}[htbp]
    \begin{adjustwidth}{-1.2cm}{-1.2cm}
      \centering\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}\footnotesize\color{white}
    \setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
      \caption{Add caption}
        \begin{tabular}{@{}>{\color{black}\bfseries}l*{15}{S[table-format=2.1, table-alignment=center]}
        S[table-format=-2.1, table-alignment=center]@{}}
    \cmidrule{2-16} \multicolumn{1}{>{\color{black}\bfseries}r}{Decades: } &
          \multicolumn{5}{>{\color{black}\bfseries}c}{\textbf{20s}} &
          \multicolumn{5}{>{\color{black}\bfseries}c}{\textbf{50s}} &
          \multicolumn{5}{>{\color{black}\bfseries}c}{\textbf{80s}} &
          \\
          \arrayrulecolor{black}
        \cmidrule(lr){2-6} \cmidrule(lr){7-11}\cmidrule(lr){12-16}
Parameter &
      {\begin{sideways}\color{black}RCP2.6\end{sideways}} &
     {\begin{sideways}\color{black}RCP4.5\end{sideways}} &
     {\begin{sideways}\color{black}RCP6\end{sideways}}&
    {\begin{sideways}\color{black}RCP8.5\end{sideways}} &
     {\begin{sideways}\color{black}Average\end{sideways}} &
    {\begin{sideways}\color{black}RCP2.6\end{sideways}} &
     {\begin{sideways}\color{black}RCP4.5\end{sideways}} &
     {\begin{sideways}\color{black}RCP6\end{sideways}} &
     {\begin{sideways}\color{black}RCP8.5\end{sideways}} &
     {\begin{sideways}\color{black}Average\end{sideways}} &
     {\begin{sideways}\color{black}RCP2.6\end{sideways}} &
     {\begin{sideways}\color{black}RCP4.5\end{sideways}} &
     {\begin{sideways}\color{black}RCP6\end{sideways}} &
     {\begin{sideways}\color{black}RCP8.5\end{sideways}} &
        {\rotatebox{90}{\color{black}Average}} &
     {\thead[bc]{Average\\ change\\ from 20s\\ to 80s}}
          \\
    \cmidrule[\lightrulewidth](r{-4pt}){1-17}\addlinespace[-\belowrulesep]
          \rowcolor[rgb]{ .149, .149, .149}
    \cellcolor{white}\textbf{ALPHA\_BF} &
    1.0 & 1.0 & 1.0 & 1.0 & 1.0 & 1.0 & 1.0 & 1.0 & 1.0 & 1.0 & 1.0 & 1.0 & 1.0 & 1.0 & 1.0 &
          {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .682, .667, .667}}0.0
          \\
    ESCO &
          {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .196, .192, .192}}2.8 &
          {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .188, .188, .188}}2.5 &
          {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .2, .196, .196}}2.9 &
          {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .192, .192, .192}}2.7 &
          {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .192, .192, .192}}2.7 &
          {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .184, .184, .184}}2.4 &
          {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .184, .18, .18}}2.3 &
          {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .188, .188, .188}}2.6 &
          {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .18, .18, .18}}2.2 &
          {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .184, .184, .184}}2.4 &
          {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .192, .188, .188}}2.7 &
          {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .18, .18, .18}}2.3 &
          {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .184, .184, .184}}2.4 &
          {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .176, .176, .176}}2.1 &
          {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .18, .18, .18}}2.3 &
          {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .682, .667, .667}}17.8
          \\
    CH\_K(II) &
          {{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .192, .192, .192}}}2.8 &
          {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .192, .192, .192}}2.8 &
          {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .188, .184, .184}}2.5 &
          {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .188, .188, .188}}2.6 &
          {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .192, .188, .188}}2.7 &
          {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .2, .196, .196}}3.0 &
          {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .196, .192, .192}}2.8 &
          {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .192, .188, .188}}2.6 &
          {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .196, .192, .192}}2.8 &
          {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .196, .192, .192}}2.8 &
          {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .192, .188, .188}}2.7 &
          {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .2, .196, .196}}2.9 &
          {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .192, .188, .188}}2.6 &
          {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .2, .196, .196}}2.9 &
          {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .196, .192, .192}}2.8 &
          {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .404, .396, .396}}-5.0
          \\
     SNO50COV &
          {{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .22, .216, .216}}} 3.7 &
          {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .224, .224, .224}}3.9 &
          {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .224, .22, .22}}3.9 &
          {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .227, .224, .224}}4.0 &
          {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .224, .224, .224}}3.9 &
          {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .224, .22, .22}}3.9 &
          {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .231, .231, .231}}4.2 &
          {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .227, .224, .224}}4.0 &
          {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .239, .235, .235}}4.4 &
          {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .231, .227, .227}}4.2 &
          {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .224, .224, .224}}3.9 &
          {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .235, .231, .231}}4.3 &
          {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .239, .239, .239}}4.5 &
          {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .259, .255, .255}}5.2 &
          {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .239, .235, .235}}4.5 &
          {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .302, .298, .298}}-13.4
     \\
    SFTMP &
    { {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .259, .255, .255}}}5.2 &
     {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .263, .259, .259}}5.3 &
     {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .259, .255, .255}}5.2 &
     {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .267, .263, .263}} 5.5 &
     {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .263, .259, .259}}5.3 &
     {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .263, .259, .259}}5.3 &
     {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .255, .251, .251}}5.0 &
     {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .259, .255, .255}}5.2 &
     {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .251, .247, .247}}4.9 &
     {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .255, .255, .255}}5.1 &
     {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .263, .259, .259}}5.4 &
     {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .255, .251, .251}}5.1 &
     {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .247, .247, .247}}4.8 &
     {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .243, .243, .243}}4.6 &
     {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .251, .251, .251}}5.0 &
     {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .549, .537, .537}}7.1
     \\
    CH\_K(I)&
     {{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .271, .267, .267}}}5.6 &
     {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .271, .267, .267}}5.6 &
     {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .271, .267, .267}}5.6 &
     {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .263, .259, .259}}5.3 &
     {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .267, .263, .263}}5.5 &
     {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .271, .267, .267}}5.6 &
     {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .275, .271, .271}}5.7 &
     {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .271, .267, .267}}5.7 &
     {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .271, .267, .267}}5.6 &
     {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .271, .267, .267}}5.6 &
     {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .267, .263, .263}}5.5 &
     {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .271, .267, .267}}5.6 &
     {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .271, .267, .267}}5.7 &
     {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .259, .255, .255}}5.2 &
     {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .267, .263, .263}}5.5 &
     {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .471, .459, .459}}0.4
     \\
 SNOCOVMX &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .31, .306, .306}}7.1 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .306, .302, .302}}7.0 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .306, .302, .302}}7.0 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .306, .302, .302}}7.0 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .306, .302, .302}}7.0 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .31, .306, .306}}7.2 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .31, .306, .306}}7.1 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .306, .302, .302}}7.0 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .322, .318, .318}}7.6 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .314, .31, .31}}7.2 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .318, .31, .31}}7.4 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .314, .306, .306}}7.2 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .325, .318, .318}}7.6 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .369, .361, .361}}9.2 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .333, .325, .325}}7.9 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .325, .318, .318}}-11.6
 \\
 GWQMN &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .349, .345, .345}}8.6 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .353, .345, .345}}8.7 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .349, .345, .345}}8.6 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .349, .341, .341}}8.6 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .349, .345, .345}}8.6 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .349, .341, .341}}8.5 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .345, .341, .341}}8.5 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .341, .333, .333}}8.3 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .333, .325, .325}}8.0 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .341, .337, .337}}8.3 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .349, .341, .341}}8.5 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .341, .337, .337}}8.3 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .329, .322, .322}}7.8 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .318, .314, .314}}7.4 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .333, .329, .329}}8.0 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .553, .541, .541}}7.3
 \\
 SMTMP &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .361, .353, .353}}9.0 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .361, .353, .353}}9.0 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .349, .345, .345}}8.6 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .361, .353, .353}}9.0 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .357, .353, .353}}8.9 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .353, .349, .349}}8.8 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .353, .349, .349}}8.8 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .365, .357, .357}}9.1 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .361, .353, .353}}9.0 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .357, .353, .353}}8.9 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .357, .349, .349}}8.9 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .353, .349, .349}}8.8 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .361, .353, .353}}9.0 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .384, .376, .376}}9.9 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .365, .357, .357}}9.2 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .431, .424, .424}}-2.8
 \\
 SOL\_AWC &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .416, .408, .408}}11.1 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .42, .412, .412}}11.3 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .424, .416, .416}}11.4 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .416, .408, .408}}11.0 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .42, .412, .412}}11.2 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .4, .396, .396}}10.6 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .396, .388, .388}}10.3 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .412, .404, .404}}10.9 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .384, .38, .38}}10.0 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .396, .388, .388}}10.4 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .404, .4, .4}}10.7 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .392, .384, .384}}10.2 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .38, .376, .376}}9.8 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .357, .353, .353}}8.9 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .384, .376, .376}}9.9 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .627, .612, .612}}13.4
 \\
 CN2 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .384, .376, .376}}9.8 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .369, .365, .365}}9.4 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .38, .373, .373}}9.8 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .384, .376, .376}}9.9 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .38, .373, .373}}9.7 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .416, .408, .408}}11.1 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .431, .424, .424}}11.7 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .404, .396, .396}}10.6 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .435, .427, .427}}11.8 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .424, .416, .416}}11.4 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .42, .412, .412}}11.2 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .498, .49, .49}}14.2 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .451, .443, .443}}12.4 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .498, .486, .486}}14.1 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .471, .463, .463}}13.1 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .149, .149, .149}}-26.1
 \\
 CANMX &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .475, .467, .467}}13.3 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .471, .463, .463}}13.1 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .467, .459, .459}}13.0 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .494, .482, .482}}14.0 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .478, .467, .467}}13.4 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .471, .463, .463}}13.2 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .471, .463, .463}}13.2 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .471, .463, .463}}13.2 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .471, .463, .463}}13.2 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .471, .463, .463}}13.2 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .467, .455, .455}}13.0 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .459, .447, .447}}12.6 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .471, .459, .459}}13.1 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .439, .431, .431}}12.0 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .455, .447, .447}}12.6 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .541, .529, .529}}6.3
 \\
 DDRAIN &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .502, .494, .494}}14.3 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .51, .498, .498}}14.6 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .525, .514, .514}}15.2 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .486, .475, .475}}13.7 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .502, .494, .494}}14.4 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .486, .475, .475}}13.7 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .471, .459, .459}}13.1 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .478, .467, .467}}13.4 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .467, .459, .459}}13.0 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .475, .463, .463}}13.3 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .475, .463, .463}}13.3 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .463, .451, .451}}12.8 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .451, .443, .443}}12.4 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .427, .42, .42}}11.6 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .455, .443, .443}}12.5 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .651, .635, .635}}15.3
 \\
 SURLAG &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .478, .467, .467}}13.3 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .463, .451, .451}}12.8 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .471, .463, .463}}13.2 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .475, .463, .463}}13.2 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .471, .459, .459}}13.1 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .494, .482, .482}}14.0 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .486, .475, .475}}13.7 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .502, .49, .49}}14.3 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .478, .467, .467}}13.4 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .486, .478, .478}}13.8 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .482, .475, .475}}13.6 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .463, .455, .455}}12.9 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .482, .471, .471}}13.6 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .482, .471, .471}}13.5 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .478, .467, .467}}13.4 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .443, .435, .435}}-1.8
 \\
 CH\_N(I) &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .518, .51, .51}}14.9 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .51, .498, .498}}14.6 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .522, .51, .51}}15.1 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .51, .498, .498}}14.6 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .514, .502, .502}}14.8 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .522, .51, .51}}15.1 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .506, .494, .494}}14.5 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .502, .49, .49}}14.3 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .506, .494, .494}}14.4 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .51, .498, .498}}14.6 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .51, .502, .502}}14.7 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .51, .498, .498}}14.5 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .506, .498, .498}}14.5 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .482, .471, .471}}13.5 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .502, .49, .49}}14.3 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .506, .498, .498}}3.5
 \\
 TIMP &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .518, .51, .51}}14.9 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .525, .514, .514}}15.2 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .525, .514, .514}}15.1 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .522, .51, .51}}15.0 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .522, .51, .51}}15.0 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .514, .502, .502}}14.7 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .525, .514, .514}}15.2 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .518, .506, .506}}14.9 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .525, .514, .514}}15.2 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .522, .51, .51}}15.0 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .537, .525, .525}}15.6 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .522, .51, .51}}15.1 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .529, .518, .518}}15.3 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .533, .522, .522}}15.4 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .529, .518, .518}}15.4 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .439, .431, .431}}-2.0
 \\
 SMFMX &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .557, .545, .545}}16.3 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .573, .561, .561}}16.9 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .549, .537, .537}}16.0 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .565, .553, .553}}16.6 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .561, .549, .549}}16.5 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .565, .553, .553}}16.7 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .576, .565, .565}}17.1 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .561, .549, .549}}16.6 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .584, .573, .573}}17.4 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .573, .561, .561}}17.0 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .553, .541, .541}}16.2 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .573, .561, .561}}17.0 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .588, .573, .573}}17.5 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .604, .588, .588}}18.1 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .58, .565, .565}}17.2 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .416, .408, .408}}-4.1
 \\
 SMFMN &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .592, .58, .58}}17.7 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .588, .573, .573}}17.5 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .573, .561, .561}}17.0 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .58, .569, .569}}17.2 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .584, .573, .573}}17.4 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .565, .553, .553}}16.7 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .576, .565, .565}}17.1 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .584, .573, .573}}17.4 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .569, .557, .557}}16.9 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .573, .561, .561}}17.0 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .576, .565, .565}}17.1 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .561, .549, .549}}16.5 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .573, .561, .561}}16.9 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .565, .553, .553}}16.6 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .569, .557, .557}}16.8 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .51, .498, .498}}3.6
 \\
 CH\_N(II) &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .631, .616, .616}}19.0 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .627, .612, .612}}19.0 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .627, .612, .612}}19.0 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .627, .612, .612}}19.0 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .627, .612, .612}}19.0 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .627, .612, .612}}19.0 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .62, .608, .608}}18.8 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .627, .612, .612}}19.0 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .627, .612, .612}}19.0 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .627, .612, .612}}18.9 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .627, .612, .612}}19.0 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .624, .608, .608}}18.8 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .627, .612, .612}}19.0 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .62, .604, .604}}18.7 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .624, .608, .608}}18.9 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .475, .463, .463}}0.7
 \\
 GDRAIN &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .671, .655, .655}}20.5 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .667, .651, .651}}20.5 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .671, .655, .655}}20.6 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .663, .647, .647}}20.3 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .667, .651, .651}}20.5 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .671, .655, .655}}20.6 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .663, .647, .647}}20.4 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .667, .651, .651}}20.5 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .663, .647, .647}}20.3 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .667, .651, .651}}20.4 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .659, .647, .647}}20.3 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .667, .651, .651}}20.5 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .667, .651, .651}}20.4 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .663, .647, .647}}20.3 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .663, .647, .647}}20.4 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .471, .463, .463}}0.6
 \\
 GW\_DELAY &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .682, .667, .667}}20.9 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .678, .663, .663}}21.0 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .678, .663, .663}}20.9 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .682, .667, .667}}21.0 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .678, .663, .663}}21.0 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .678, .663, .663}}21.0 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .682, .667, .667}}21.0 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .678, .663, .663}}20.9 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .678, .663, .663}}21.0 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .678, .663, .663}}21.0 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .682, .667, .667}}21.0 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .682, .667, .667}}21.0 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .682, .667, .667}}21.0 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .678, .663, .663}}20.9 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .678, .663, .663}}21.0 &
 {\cellcolor[rgb]{ .463, .455, .455}}-0.1
          \\\addlinespace[-\aboverulesep]
        \cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth](r{-4pt}){1-17}
        \end{tabular}%
      \label{tab:addlabel}%
      \end{adjustwidth}
    \end{table}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I use command \raisebox for those cells. If you use package booktab you don't want vertical lines.

```
            \documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
            \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
            \usepackage{booktabs}
            \usepackage{multirow,color}
            \usepackage[Table]{xcolor}
            \usepackage{colortbl}
            \usepackage{rotating}
            \usepackage{adjustbox}
            \begin{document}
            \onecolumn
            % Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Table 3'
            \begin{table}[htbp]
              \centering
              \caption{Add caption}
            \begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth}
                \begin{tabular}{lcccccccccccccccc}
            \cmidrule{2-16}    \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &
              \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{20s}} &
              \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{50s}} &
              \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{80s}} &

              \\
            \midrule
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{\raisebox{1.5\height}{\textbf{Parameter}}} &
              \begin{sideways}RCP2.6\end{sideways} &
              \begin{sideways}RCP4.5\end{sideways} &
              \begin{sideways}RCP6\end{sideways} &
              \begin{sideways}RCP8.5\end{sideways} &
              \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\begin{sideways}Average\end{sideways}} &
              \begin{sideways}RCP2.6\end{sideways} &
              \begin{sideways}RCP4.5\end{sideways} &
              \begin{sideways}RCP6\end{sideways} &
              \begin{sideways}RCP8.5\end{sideways} &
              \multicolumn{1}{c}{\begin{sideways}Average\end{sideways}} &
              \begin{sideways}RCP2.6\end{sideways} &
              \begin{sideways}RCP4.5\end{sideways} &
              \begin{sideways}RCP6\end{sideways} &
              \begin{sideways}RCP8.5\end{sideways} &
              \multicolumn{1}{c}{\begin{sideways}Average\end{sideways}} &
              \raisebox{1.5\height}{\textbf{Average change from 20s to 80s}}
              \\
            \cmidrule{1-17}    \rowcolor[rgb]{ 1,1,1} \textbf{ALPHA\_BF} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .149,  .149,  .149}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{1.0} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .149,  .149,  .149}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{1.0} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .149,  .149,  .149}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{1.0} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .149,  .149,  .149}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{1.0} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .149,  .149,  .149}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{1.0} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .149,  .149,  .149}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{1.0} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .149,  .149,  .149}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{1.0} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .149,  .149,  .149}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{1.0} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .149,  .149,  .149}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{1.0} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .149,  .149,  .149}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{1.0} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .149,  .149,  .149}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{1.0} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .149,  .149,  .149}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{1.0} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .149,  .149,  .149}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{1.0} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .149,  .149,  .149}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{1.0} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .149,  .149,  .149}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{1.0} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{0.0}
              \\
            \rowcolor[rgb]{ 1,1,1} \textbf{ESCO} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .196,  .192,  .192}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{2.8} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .188,  .188,  .188}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{2.5} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .2,  .196,  .196}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{2.9} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .192,  .192,  .192}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{2.7} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .192,  .192,  .192}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{2.7} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .184,  .184,  .184}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{2.4} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .184,  .18,  .18}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{2.3} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .188,  .188,  .188}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{2.6} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .18,  .18,  .18}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{2.2} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .184,  .184,  .184}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{2.4} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .192,  .188,  .188}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{2.7} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .18,  .18,  .18}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{2.3} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .184,  .184,  .184}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{2.4} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .176,  .176,  .176}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{2.1} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .18,  .18,  .18}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{2.3} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{17.8}
              \\
            \rowcolor[rgb]{ 1,1,1} \textbf{CH\_K(II)} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .192,  .192,  .192}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{2.8} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .192,  .192,  .192}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{2.8} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .188,  .184,  .184}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{2.5} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .188,  .188,  .188}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{2.6} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .192,  .188,  .188}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{2.7} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .2,  .196,  .196}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{3.0} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .196,  .192,  .192}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{2.8} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .192,  .188,  .188}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{2.6} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .196,  .192,  .192}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{2.8} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .196,  .192,  .192}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{2.8} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .192,  .188,  .188}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{2.7} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .2,  .196,  .196}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{2.9} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .192,  .188,  .188}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{2.6} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .2,  .196,  .196}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{2.9} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .196,  .192,  .192}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{2.8} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .404,  .396,  .396}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{-5.0}
              \\
            \rowcolor[rgb]{ 1,1,1} \textbf{SNO50COV} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .22,  .216,  .216}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{3.7} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .224,  .224,  .224}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{3.9} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .224,  .22,  .22}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{3.9} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .227,  .224,  .224}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{4.0} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .224,  .224,  .224}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{3.9} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .224,  .22,  .22}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{3.9} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .231,  .231,  .231}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{4.2} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .227,  .224,  .224}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{4.0} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .239,  .235,  .235}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{4.4} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .231,  .227,  .227}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{4.2} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .224,  .224,  .224}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{3.9} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .235,  .231,  .231}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{4.3} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .239,  .239,  .239}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{4.5} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .259,  .255,  .255}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{5.2} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .239,  .235,  .235}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{4.5} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .302,  .298,  .298}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{-13.4}
              \\
            \rowcolor[rgb]{ 1,1,1} \textbf{SFTMP} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .259,  .255,  .255}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{5.2} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .263,  .259,  .259}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{5.3} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .259,  .255,  .255}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{5.2} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .267,  .263,  .263}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{5.5} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .263,  .259,  .259}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{5.3} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .263,  .259,  .259}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{5.3} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .255,  .251,  .251}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{5.0} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .259,  .255,  .255}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{5.2} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .251,  .247,  .247}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{4.9} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .255,  .255,  .255}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{5.1} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .263,  .259,  .259}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{5.4} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .255,  .251,  .251}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{5.1} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .247,  .247,  .247}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{4.8} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .243,  .243,  .243}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{4.6} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .251,  .251,  .251}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{5.0} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .549,  .537,  .537}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{7.1}
              \\
            \rowcolor[rgb]{ 1,1,1} \textbf{CH\_K(I)} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .271,  .267,  .267}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{5.6} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .271,  .267,  .267}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{5.6} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .271,  .267,  .267}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{5.6} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .263,  .259,  .259}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{5.3} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .267,  .263,  .263}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{5.5} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .271,  .267,  .267}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{5.6} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .275,  .271,  .271}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{5.7} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .271,  .267,  .267}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{5.7} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .271,  .267,  .267}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{5.6} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .271,  .267,  .267}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{5.6} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .267,  .263,  .263}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{5.5} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .271,  .267,  .267}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{5.6} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .271,  .267,  .267}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{5.7} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .259,  .255,  .255}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{5.2} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .267,  .263,  .263}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{5.5} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .471,  .459,  .459}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{0.4}
              \\
            \rowcolor[rgb]{ 1,1,1} \textbf{SNOCOVMX} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .31,  .306,  .306}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{7.1} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .306,  .302,  .302}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{7.0} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .306,  .302,  .302}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{7.0} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .306,  .302,  .302}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{7.0} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .306,  .302,  .302}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{7.0} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .31,  .306,  .306}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{7.2} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .31,  .306,  .306}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{7.1} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .306,  .302,  .302}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{7.0} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .322,  .318,  .318}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{7.6} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .314,  .31,  .31}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{7.2} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .318,  .31,  .31}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{7.4} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .314,  .306,  .306}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{7.2} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .325,  .318,  .318}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{7.6} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .369,  .361,  .361}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{9.2} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .333,  .325,  .325}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{7.9} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .325,  .318,  .318}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{-11.6}
              \\
            \rowcolor[rgb]{ 1,1,1} \textbf{GWQMN} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .349,  .345,  .345}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{8.6} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .353,  .345,  .345}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{8.7} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .349,  .345,  .345}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{8.6} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .349,  .341,  .341}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{8.6} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .349,  .345,  .345}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{8.6} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .349,  .341,  .341}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{8.5} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .345,  .341,  .341}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{8.5} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .341,  .333,  .333}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{8.3} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .333,  .325,  .325}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{8.0} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .341,  .337,  .337}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{8.3} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .349,  .341,  .341}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{8.5} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .341,  .337,  .337}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{8.3} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .329,  .322,  .322}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{7.8} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .318,  .314,  .314}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{7.4} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .333,  .329,  .329}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{8.0} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .553,  .541,  .541}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{7.3}
              \\
            \rowcolor[rgb]{ 1,1,1} \textbf{SMTMP} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .361,  .353,  .353}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{9.0} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .361,  .353,  .353}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{9.0} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .349,  .345,  .345}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{8.6} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .361,  .353,  .353}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{9.0} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .357,  .353,  .353}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{8.9} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .353,  .349,  .349}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{8.8} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .353,  .349,  .349}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{8.8} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .365,  .357,  .357}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{9.1} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .361,  .353,  .353}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{9.0} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .357,  .353,  .353}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{8.9} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .357,  .349,  .349}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{8.9} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .353,  .349,  .349}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{8.8} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .361,  .353,  .353}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{9.0} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .384,  .376,  .376}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{9.9} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .365,  .357,  .357}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{9.2} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .431,  .424,  .424}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{-2.8}
              \\
            \rowcolor[rgb]{ 1,1,1} \textbf{SOL\_AWC} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .416,  .408,  .408}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{11.1} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .42,  .412,  .412}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{11.3} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .424,  .416,  .416}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{11.4} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .416,  .408,  .408}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{11.0} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .42,  .412,  .412}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{11.2} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .4,  .396,  .396}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{10.6} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .396,  .388,  .388}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{10.3} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .412,  .404,  .404}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{10.9} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .384,  .38,  .38}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{10.0} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .396,  .388,  .388}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{10.4} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .404,  .4,  .4}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{10.7} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .392,  .384,  .384}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{10.2} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .38,  .376,  .376}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{9.8} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .357,  .353,  .353}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{8.9} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .384,  .376,  .376}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{9.9} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .627,  .612,  .612}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{13.4}
              \\
            \rowcolor[rgb]{ 1,1,1} \textbf{CN2} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .384,  .376,  .376}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{9.8} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .369,  .365,  .365}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{9.4} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .38,  .373,  .373}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{9.8} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .384,  .376,  .376}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{9.9} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .38,  .373,  .373}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{9.7} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .416,  .408,  .408}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{11.1} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .431,  .424,  .424}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{11.7} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .404,  .396,  .396}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{10.6} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .435,  .427,  .427}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{11.8} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .424,  .416,  .416}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{11.4} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .42,  .412,  .412}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{11.2} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .498,  .49,  .49}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{14.2} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .451,  .443,  .443}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{12.4} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .498,  .486,  .486}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{14.1} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .471,  .463,  .463}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{13.1} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .149,  .149,  .149}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{-26.1}
              \\
            \rowcolor[rgb]{ 1,1,1} \textbf{CANMX} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .475,  .467,  .467}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{13.3} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .471,  .463,  .463}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{13.1} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .467,  .459,  .459}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{13.0} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .494,  .482,  .482}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{14.0} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .478,  .467,  .467}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{13.4} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .471,  .463,  .463}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{13.2} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .471,  .463,  .463}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{13.2} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .471,  .463,  .463}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{13.2} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .471,  .463,  .463}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{13.2} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .471,  .463,  .463}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{13.2} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .467,  .455,  .455}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{13.0} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .459,  .447,  .447}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{12.6} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .471,  .459,  .459}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{13.1} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .439,  .431,  .431}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{12.0} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .455,  .447,  .447}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{12.6} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .541,  .529,  .529}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{6.3}
              \\
            \rowcolor[rgb]{ 1,1,1} \textbf{DDRAIN} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .502,  .494,  .494}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{14.3} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .51,  .498,  .498}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{14.6} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .525,  .514,  .514}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{15.2} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .486,  .475,  .475}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{13.7} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .502,  .494,  .494}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{14.4} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .486,  .475,  .475}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{13.7} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .471,  .459,  .459}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{13.1} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .478,  .467,  .467}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{13.4} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .467,  .459,  .459}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{13.0} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .475,  .463,  .463}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{13.3} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .475,  .463,  .463}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{13.3} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .463,  .451,  .451}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{12.8} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .451,  .443,  .443}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{12.4} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .427,  .42,  .42}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{11.6} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .455,  .443,  .443}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{12.5} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .651,  .635,  .635}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{15.3}
              \\
            \rowcolor[rgb]{ 1,1,1} \textbf{SURLAG} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .478,  .467,  .467}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{13.3} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .463,  .451,  .451}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{12.8} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .471,  .463,  .463}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{13.2} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .475,  .463,  .463}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{13.2} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .471,  .459,  .459}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{13.1} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .494,  .482,  .482}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{14.0} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .486,  .475,  .475}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{13.7} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .502,  .49,  .49}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{14.3} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .478,  .467,  .467}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{13.4} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .486,  .478,  .478}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{13.8} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .482,  .475,  .475}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{13.6} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .463,  .455,  .455}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{12.9} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .482,  .471,  .471}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{13.6} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .482,  .471,  .471}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{13.5} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .478,  .467,  .467}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{13.4} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .443,  .435,  .435}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{-1.8}
              \\
            \rowcolor[rgb]{ 1,1,1} \textbf{CH\_N(I)} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .518,  .51,  .51}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{14.9} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .51,  .498,  .498}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{14.6} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .522,  .51,  .51}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{15.1} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .51,  .498,  .498}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{14.6} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .514,  .502,  .502}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{14.8} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .522,  .51,  .51}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{15.1} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .506,  .494,  .494}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{14.5} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .502,  .49,  .49}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{14.3} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .506,  .494,  .494}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{14.4} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .51,  .498,  .498}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{14.6} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .51,  .502,  .502}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{14.7} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .51,  .498,  .498}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{14.5} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .506,  .498,  .498}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{14.5} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .482,  .471,  .471}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{13.5} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .502,  .49,  .49}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{14.3} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .506,  .498,  .498}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{3.5}
              \\
            \rowcolor[rgb]{ 1,1,1} \textbf{TIMP} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .518,  .51,  .51}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{14.9} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .525,  .514,  .514}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{15.2} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .525,  .514,  .514}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{15.1} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .522,  .51,  .51}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{15.0} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .522,  .51,  .51}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{15.0} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .514,  .502,  .502}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{14.7} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .525,  .514,  .514}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{15.2} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .518,  .506,  .506}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{14.9} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .525,  .514,  .514}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{15.2} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .522,  .51,  .51}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{15.0} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .537,  .525,  .525}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{15.6} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .522,  .51,  .51}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{15.1} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .529,  .518,  .518}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{15.3} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .533,  .522,  .522}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{15.4} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .529,  .518,  .518}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{15.4} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .439,  .431,  .431}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{-2.0}
              \\
            \rowcolor[rgb]{ 1,1,1} \textbf{SMFMX} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .557,  .545,  .545}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{16.3} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .573,  .561,  .561}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{16.9} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .549,  .537,  .537}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{16.0} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .565,  .553,  .553}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{16.6} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .561,  .549,  .549}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{16.5} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .565,  .553,  .553}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{16.7} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .576,  .565,  .565}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{17.1} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .561,  .549,  .549}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{16.6} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .584,  .573,  .573}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{17.4} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .573,  .561,  .561}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{17.0} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .553,  .541,  .541}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{16.2} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .573,  .561,  .561}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{17.0} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .588,  .573,  .573}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{17.5} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .604,  .588,  .588}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{18.1} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .58,  .565,  .565}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{17.2} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .416,  .408,  .408}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{-4.1}
              \\
            \rowcolor[rgb]{ 1,1,1} \textbf{SMFMN} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .592,  .58,  .58}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{17.7} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .588,  .573,  .573}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{17.5} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .573,  .561,  .561}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{17.0} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .58,  .569,  .569}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{17.2} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .584,  .573,  .573}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{17.4} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .565,  .553,  .553}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{16.7} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .576,  .565,  .565}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{17.1} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .584,  .573,  .573}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{17.4} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .569,  .557,  .557}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{16.9} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .573,  .561,  .561}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{17.0} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .576,  .565,  .565}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{17.1} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .561,  .549,  .549}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{16.5} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .573,  .561,  .561}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{16.9} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .565,  .553,  .553}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{16.6} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .569,  .557,  .557}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{16.8} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .51,  .498,  .498}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{3.6}
              \\
            \rowcolor[rgb]{ 1,1,1} \textbf{CH\_N(II)} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .631,  .616,  .616}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{19.0} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .627,  .612,  .612}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{19.0} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .627,  .612,  .612}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{19.0} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .627,  .612,  .612}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{19.0} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .627,  .612,  .612}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{19.0} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .627,  .612,  .612}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{19.0} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .62,  .608,  .608}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{18.8} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .627,  .612,  .612}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{19.0} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .627,  .612,  .612}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{19.0} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .627,  .612,  .612}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{18.9} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .627,  .612,  .612}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{19.0} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .624,  .608,  .608}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{18.8} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .627,  .612,  .612}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{19.0} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .62,  .604,  .604}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{18.7} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .624,  .608,  .608}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{18.9} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .475,  .463,  .463}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{0.7}
              \\
            \rowcolor[rgb]{ 1,1,1} \textbf{GDRAIN} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .671,  .655,  .655}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{20.5} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .667,  .651,  .651}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{20.5} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .671,  .655,  .655}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{20.6} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .647,  .647}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{20.3} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .667,  .651,  .651}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{20.5} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .671,  .655,  .655}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{20.6} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .647,  .647}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{20.4} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .667,  .651,  .651}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{20.5} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .647,  .647}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{20.3} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .667,  .651,  .651}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{20.4} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .659,  .647,  .647}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{20.3} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .667,  .651,  .651}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{20.5} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .667,  .651,  .651}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{20.4} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .647,  .647}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{20.3} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .663,  .647,  .647}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{20.4} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .471,  .463,  .463}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{0.6}
              \\
            \rowcolor[rgb]{ 1,1,1} \textbf{GW\_DELAY} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{20.9} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .678,  .663,  .663}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{21.0} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .678,  .663,  .663}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{20.9} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{21.0} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .678,  .663,  .663}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{21.0} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .678,  .663,  .663}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{21.0} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{21.0} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .678,  .663,  .663}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{20.9} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .678,  .663,  .663}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{21.0} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .678,  .663,  .663}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{21.0} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{21.0} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{21.0} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .682,  .667,  .667}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{21.0} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .678,  .663,  .663}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{20.9} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .678,  .663,  .663}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{21.0} &
              \cellcolor[rgb]{ .463,  .455,  .455}\textcolor[rgb]{ 1,  1,  1}{-0.1}
              \\
            \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}%
            \label{tab:addlabel}%
            \end{adjustbox}
            \end{table}
            \end{document}
```